# Maven offline build fails when it encouners google guava url with invalid character

Tags: eclipse, maven, guava, eclipse-cdt, tycho

I need to make my Tycho-Maven build work in offline mode, so I can deploy it to environments with no Internet connection and let people run the build from the previously downloaded artifacts for the third party code my app depends on. The product being built is an Eclipse RCP product, using the `org.eclipse.tycho:target-platform-configuration` plug-in to load the dependencies from an RCP target file.

First I run `mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=/some/path/ -DgeneratePom=true clean install` to create the artifacts, and that build succeeds. Then when I run `mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=/some/path/ -o clean install` it fails because it's running in offline mode and there is no local cache available for `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.6`

So then I run `mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=/some/path/ dependency:go-offline` to make it download all the artifacts it needs for the build, but it fails with this message:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:resolve-plugins
>   (resolve-plugins) on project : Nested: Could not transfer
>   artifact com.google.guava:guava:jar:[10.0.1,14.0.1] from/to central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Illegal character in path at
>   index 60:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/[10.0.1,14.0.1]/guava-[10.0.1,14.0.1].jar

Index 60 is the "[" character in the version range specifier for the guava jar. I have no idea where that URL gets created and why it's not URL-encoded. It would be nice to get the dependency:go-offline goal to complete execution, but I don't think it's the source of my problem.

The reason I say that is when I run that goal, I see this in the output

> [INFO] Adding repository
>   http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.6 [INFO] Fetching
>   p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.6/r/
>   (0B at 0B/s)

I don't know why it downloads 0 Bytes, but I assume this is why I can't find a cache of the CDT bundles when I try to do an offline build.

If anyone has an idea how to work around this failure, or any other approach to make an offline build work, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Looks like a bug. File a JIRA at issues.apache.org.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that and post the link here. But I assume you're referring to the invalid character error while running dep[endency:go-ofline. Do you think the failure to find the CDT artifacts in the cache is related, or a separate issue? I don't know what to make of it reporting 0 bytes downloaded from the CDT site and later complaining it can't find CDT artifacts. I can ask a separate question for the CDT failure if it's unrelated.

Comment: Tycho does not integrate with `dependency:go-offline`, so in the best case this will do nothing for the project's p2 dependencies.

Comment: Where does the version range dependency to guava come from? The fact that the dependency-plugin is trying to download it from a Maven repository indicates that this is a non-Tycho dependency.

Comment: I'm in the process of creating a stripped-down project that demonstrates the problem. So far it seems that it's org.eclipse.xtext.ui depending on google.guava.

Comment: Since tycho doesn't integrate with `dependency:go-offline`, what is the suggested way to do an offline build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the course of creating a stripped down project to demonstrate the problem, I discovered the cause. The presence of  `org.eclipse.xtend:xtend-maven-plugin` in the pom was causing the problem. The plug-in is not used, and was perhaps misconfigured, per a message I saw in the build output.

Answer (score 0):

I created this [Maven bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5902) in the issue tracker.

Comment: I close the issue as invalid