# Maven Offline Build fails, can't find cache for Eclipse CDT artifacts

Tags: maven, eclipse-cdt, offline, tycho, target-platform

I'm trying to create a local cache of artifacts so I can build my Maven project offline, and it fails to create a cache artifact for an Eclipse CDT feature, so the offline build cannot succeed.

I create the local repository artifacts by running `mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=/some/path/ -DgeneratePom=true clean install`, and that build succeeds.

Then I run `mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=/some/path/ -o clean install`, and it fails with this error message.

> ERROR] Failed to resolve target definition
>   /opt/git/myproject/my.package.target/my.package.target.target:
>   Failed to load p2 metadata repository from location
>   http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.6: Repository system
>   is offline and no local cache available for
>   http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.6 -> [Help 1]

So then I try to create the needed artifacts by running `mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=/some/path/ dependency:go-offline`. I see the following on the console, which seems to indicate that it either tries and fails to find the CDT artifacts, or thinks the artifacts are already cached.

> INFO] Adding repository
>   http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.6 [INFO] Fetching
>   p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.6/r/
>   (0B at 0B/s)

I'd like to know what this message means (i.e. does 0B indicate a failurre, or that the artifact is already present?), and how I can make the offline build work. The `dependency:go-offline` build eventually fails because of a problem that is probably (?) not related to this one. Afterwards, the offline build continues to fail because it can't find the CDT artifacts.

I created [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32916951/maven-offline-build-fails-when-it-encouners-google-guava-url-with-invalid-charac/32939715#32939715) and [this Maven Jira Bug Report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5902) regarding the problem that happens downstream after the above message regarding 0 Bytes downloaded from the CDT update site.

The project I'm building is an Eclipse RCP app (based on Mars), and I'm using the `org.eclipse.tycho:target-platform-configuration` Maven plug-in to load the dependencies from an RCP target file.

Comment: Try to remove your m2 repo and run `mvn -U -Dmaven.repo.local=/some/path/ dependency:go-offline`.

Comment: I tried with the -U option. Took much longer than without it, a good sign. But it still showed 0B downloaded for the CDT site, and the go-offline goal still failed with the (probably unrelated) google guava error I saw before. After that failure, offline build still reports there are no cached artifacts for the CDT site. I'm trying to resolve the guava error so I can get the go-offline goal to complete. But I'd like to know if the 0B downloaded for the CDT site is expected behavior. It seems that getting past the guava error won't help, since it already completed processing the CDT dependency.

Comment: After one successful build, running the same build with `-o` should succeed out of the box with Tycho. If it doesn't, this could be a bug that you should rather report [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Tycho). Make sure you attach a small project that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I resolved the problem that was preventing `dependency:go-offline` from completing (documented on that SO question), and the offline build fails with the same problem, as I expected. It's complaining now about having no local cache for `http://download.eclipse.org/tm/terminal/marketplace`, I guess because of some re-arranging of the pom files. I'll create a tycho bug report as suggested.

Comment: One more question about what I'm trying: I'm relying on the RCP target to resolve my depedencies, using the plugin `org.eclipse.tycho:target-platform-configuration`. Should that work in offline mode? If not, is there something else I can do to make my build work in offline mode when it relies on the RCP target to resolve the dependencies?

Comment: I converted my project to not use the `target-platform-configuration` plugin, and offline builds still fail. I'll open a tycho bug, but I rather think there is something obvious to everyone but me, as the Internet is full of people doing offline builds, and none of the fixes they report when they had probems applied to me, e.g. deleting _maven.repositories files, etc. I also updated to maven 3.3.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created [this tycho bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=479355) for the issue. It was closed as a duplicate of another bug. In the discussion for that bug, it appears that the problem occurs if one or more of the repositories needed to satisfy the build dependencies is a composite repository.